# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./2_usr_share_lyx_images_buffer-view.pdf): reading image file failed

Tags: errors, pdftex, lyx, pdf

I am a complete beginner with latex and lyx, in order to learn I installed texlive and lyx in kubuntu using the next command:

```
sudo apt-get install lyx texlive-plain-generic ispell ispanish texlive-full texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended texlive-fonts-extra texlive-lang-spanish texlive-bibtex-extra texlive-pictures preview-latex-style texlive-publishers texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-extra lilypond lilypond-data lilypond-doc lilypond-doc-html-es lmodern && lyx -x reconfigure
```

I started reading the tutorials but when i try to compile the lyx tutorial, appear the next error:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./2_usr_share_lyx_images_buffer-view.pdf): reading image file failed
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I was searching about, and then i found a very old post here:
https://tex-live.tug.narkive.com/XxEKIHVH/including-pdf-images-fails-while-running-pdflatex
but it applies to windows, and i need a solution on Ubuntu systems.

When i compile other tutorials without pdf image files, it works, but if the tutorial has pdf image files, it crashes.

The full lyx report is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.2)  3 MAY 2021 09:48
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Tutorial.tex
(./Tutorial.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-01-09> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk12.clo
File: bk12.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count177
\c@chapter=\count178
\c@section=\count179
\c@subsection=\count180
\c@subsubsection=\count181
\c@paragraph=\count182
\c@subparagraph=\count183
\c@figure=\count184
\c@table=\count185
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen138
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/mathpazo.sty
Package: mathpazo 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 Palatino w/ Pazo Math (D.Puga, WaS) 
\symupright=\mathgroup4
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
Package: helvet 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS) 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks15
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/courier.sty
Package: courier 2020/03/25 PSNFSS-v9.3 (WaS) 
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ppl on input line 11
2.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ppl.fd
File: t1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/ppl.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks16
\inpenc@posthook=\toks17
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latin9.def
File: latin9.def 2020/08/01 v1.3d Input encoding file
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
Package: color 2020/02/24 v1.2b Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package color Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 147.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for pdftex
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2021/01/26 3.53 The Babel package
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2021/01/26 3.53 Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count186
\U@D=\dimen139
\l@babelnohyphens=\language86
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def)
\bbl@readstream=\read2
)
\bbl@dirlevel=\count187
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2017/06/06 v3.3r English support from the babel system
Package babel Info: \l@canadian = using hyphenrules for english
(babel)             (\language0) on input line 102.
Package babel Info: \l@australian = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language43) on input line 105.
Package babel Info: \l@newzealand = using hyphenrules for ukenglish
(babel)             (\language43) on input line 108.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf
Language: spanish.ldf 2016/03/03 v5.0p Spanish support from the babel system
\es@quottoks=\toks18
\es@quotdepth=\count188
Package babel Info: Making " an active character on input line 561.
Package babel Info: Making . an active character on input line 662.
Package babel Info: Making < an active character on input line 707.
Package babel Info: Making > an active character on input line 707.
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 105.
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen140
\Gin@req@width=\dimen141
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/esint.sty
Package: esint 
\symlargesymbolsA=\mathgroup5
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hypertext links for LaTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2019/12/15 v1.18 Key value parser (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2019-12-19 v1.6 Define keys (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty
Package: pdfescape 2019/12/09 v1.15 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty
Package: hycolor 2020-01-27 v1.10 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty
Package: letltxmacro 2019/12/03 v1.6 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty
Package: auxhook 2019-12-17 v1.6 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2020-10-07 v3.14 Key value format for package options (HO)
)
\@linkdim=\dimen142
\Hy@linkcounter=\count189
\Hy@pagecounter=\count190
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def
File: pd1enc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PD1 ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PD1
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty
Package: intcalc 2019/12/15 v1.3 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2019/12/15 v1.7 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
)
\Hy@SavedSpaceFactor=\count191
Package hyperref Info: Option `unicode' set `true' on input line 4338.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def
File: puenc.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
Now handling font encoding PU ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding PU
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksnumbered' set `true' on input line 4338
.
Package hyperref Info: Option `bookmarksopen' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `breaklinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Option `colorlinks' set `true' on input line 4338.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 4464.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 4469.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 4472.
Package hyperref Info: Plain pages OFF on input line 4479.
Package hyperref Info: Backreferencing OFF on input line 4484.
Package hyperref Info: Implicit mode ON; LaTeX internals redefined.
Package hyperref Info: Bookmarks ON on input line 4717.
\c@Hy@tempcnt=\count192
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip16
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \url on input line 5076.
\XeTeXLinkMargin=\dimen143
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
Package: bitset 2019/12/09 v1.3 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty
Package: bigintcalc 2019/12/15 v1.5 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO
)
))
\Fld@menulength=\count193
\Field@Width=\dimen144
\Fld@charsize=\dimen145
Package hyperref Info: Hyper figures OFF on input line 6347.
Package hyperref Info: Link nesting OFF on input line 6352.
Package hyperref Info: Hyper index ON on input line 6355.
Package hyperref Info: backreferencing OFF on input line 6362.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 6365.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring with OCG OFF on input line 6372.
Package hyperref Info: PDF/A mode OFF on input line 6377.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 6417.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 6421.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty
Package: atbegshi-ltx 2020/08/17 v1.0a Emulation of the original atbegshi packa
ge
with kernel methods
)
\Hy@abspage=\count194
\c@Item=\count195
\c@Hfootnote=\count196
)
Package hyperref Info: Driver: hpdftex.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
File: hpdftex.def 2020-05-15 v7.00e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atvery packag
e
with kernel methods
)
\Fld@listcount=\count197
\c@bookmark@seq@number=\count198
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
Package: rerunfilecheck 2019/12/05 v1.9 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty
Package: uniquecounter 2019/12/15 v1.4 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
)
Package uniquecounter Info: New unique counter `rerunfilecheck' on input line 2
86.
)
\Hy@SectionHShift=\skip49
)
Package hyperref Info: Option `pdfnewwindow' set `true' on input line 27.
Package hyperref Info: Option `plainpages' set `false' on input line 27.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2020-01-29 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count199
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box47
) (./Tutorial.aux
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 25.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 25.
)
\openout1 = `Tutorial.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PD1/pdf/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for PU/pdf/m/n on input line 65.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 65.
\big@size=\dimen146
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count266
\scratchdimen=\dimen147
\scratchbox=\box48
\nofMPsegments=\count267
\nofMParguments=\count268
\everyMPshowfont=\toks19
\MPscratchCnt=\count269
\MPscratchDim=\dimen148
\MPnumerator=\count270
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count271
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks20
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 65.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 65.
Package hyperref Info: Link coloring ON on input line 65.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
Package: nameref 2019/09/16 v2.46 Cross-referencing by name of section
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty
Package: refcount 2019/12/15 v3.6 Data extraction from label references (HO)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty
Package: gettitlestring 2019/12/15 v1.6 Cleanup title references (HO)
)
\c@section@level=\count272
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ref on input line 65.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pageref on input line 65.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nameref on input line 65.
(./Tutorial.out) (./Tutorial.out)
\@outlinefile=\write3
\openout3 = `Tutorial.out'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+ppl on input line 7
1.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ppl.fd
File: ot1ppl.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for OT1/ppl.
)
LaTeX Font linux

Info:    Trying to load font information for OML+zplm on input line 
71.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omlzplm.fd
File: omlzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OML/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMS+zplm on input line 
71.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omszplm.fd
File: omszplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMS/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OMX+zplm on input line 
71.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/omxzplm.fd
File: omxzplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OMX/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for OT1+zplm on input line 
71.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1zplm.fd
File: ot1zplm.fd 2002/09/08 Fontinst v1.914 font definitions for OT1/zplm.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+esint on input line 7
1.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/uesint.fd
File: uesint.fd 
) [1


{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2

] (./Tutorial.toc)
\tf@toc=\write4
\openout4 = `Tutorial.toc'.

[3]
LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 73.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 73.
[4

]
Cap\'{\i }tulo 1.

Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []

[5]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:latexusers' on page 6 undefined on input line 123
.

LaTeX Info: Redefining \. on input line 140.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \% on input line 140.
[6]
Cap\'{\i }tulo 2.
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+phv on input line 15
1.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd
File: t1phv.fd 2020/03/25 scalable font definitions for T1/phv.
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+pcr on input line 16
5.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1pcr.fd
File: t1pcr.fd 2001/06/04 font definitions for T1/pcr.
)
Overfull \hbox (55.88072pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 164--174
\T1/ppl/m/n/12 rien-do que co-rri-jas las par-tes co-rres-pon-dien-tes del ar-c
hi-vo \T1/pcr/m/n/12 ejemplo_sin_lyx.lyx\T1/ppl/m/n/12 .
 []

[7

]
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./2_usr_share_lyx_images_buffer-view.pdf): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

I really appreciate any help in this regard!!

2021/07/26 EDIT:

I'm using Ubuntu 21.04:

```
pc@user-X555LN:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.04
Release:        21.04
Codename:       hirsute
```

And the Lyx version is 2.3.6:

```
Versión LyX 2.3.6
(viernes, 27 de noviembre de 2020)
Directorio de bibliotecas: /usr/share/lyx/
Directorio del usuario: ~/.lyx/
Versión QT (en ejecución): 5.15.2
Versión QT (en compilación): 5.15.2
```

Introduction compiles fine, the problem appears only if I have a svgz file embed.

I created a new file, and insert the a SVGZ image file, the same problem...

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! Nice first post (thanks for giving the specific command you used to install and for formatting the pasted text so it is easy to read!). +1. What version of Ubuntu are you using? What version of LyX is it? (you can see this in Help > About). If you compile Help > Introduction, does that successfully compile to PDF? If you run `lyx` on the command line, and then compile the Tutorial, can you paste the output from the terminal that you see? My guess is that this is the ImageMagick security issue. The output you paste will help us diagnose it.

Comment: And a "Hello world" document with a PDF image? Make a PDF yourself (e.g. with inkscape)  in the same working directory, and include it in the .lyx file. If this work,  then is only a problem  of the tutorial, nothing too serious.

Comment: i have same problem. i can build the lyx-help-introduction, but not lyx-help-tutorial, (or any other file that has images). this is a fresh install of mint .

Comment: A hello world document with a .svgz file embed fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from Inkscape, the old svgz files are not automatically integrated when Lyx are compiling the PDF. To solve, it was enough to convert the files to the new standard, I solved it by running two command lines in the tutorial's folder:

```
sudo inkscape --convert-dpi-method="scale-viewbox" --export-type=svg *.svgz
sudo gzip -S z --force *.svg
```

It's necessary to use sudo, because the folder where the tutorial images are is: / usr / share / lyx / images /