# How to solve pdfTeX error: pdflatex reading image file failed?

Tags: graphics, pdftex, lyx, conversion

My freshly installed LyX on a Xubuntu 23.10 machine can't compile the splash-example, which shows up at initial start. I suspect that this might rather be a pdftex problem, because the error is the following:

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./0_usr_share_lyx_images_buffer-view.pdf): reading image file failed
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

The general problem might be (1) that pdftex does not accept the image-format (which is svgz in this case, because the above filename derives from /usr/share/lyx/images/buffer-view.svgz) or (2) fails at converting the original image to the one, where it fails. (Although I don't find a corresponding error in the latex log.)

There is a related question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/595499/72037), whose author then proposes to convert images manually before compilation, but in previous LyX installations that step was automated and there should be a way to make this work again, I think.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve that?

---

Here's the build info for LyX:

```
LyX 2.3.7 (2023-01-01)
Configuration
  Host type:               x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
  Special build flags:      build=release std-regex warnings use-enchant
  Bundled libraries:       (none)
  C++ Compiler:            g++ (12.2.0)
  C++ Compiler flags:       -Wall -Wextra -fPIC -O2 -std=c++14  -Wno-deprecated-copy
  C++ Compiler user flags:  -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -std=c++14  -g -O2 -ffile-prefix-map=/build/lyx-SNosJh/lyx-2.3.7=. -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC
  Linker flags:            
  Linker user flags:       -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -flto=auto -ffat-lto-objects -flto=auto -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now
  Qt Frontend:
      Qt version:      5.15.7
  Packaging:               posix
  LyX binary dir:          /usr/bin
  LyX files dir:           /usr/share/lyx
```

and the pdftex version:

```
> pdftex --version
pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.39; using libpng 1.6.39
Compiled with zlib 1.2.13; using zlib 1.2.13
Compiled with xpdf version 4.04
```

Comment: Nice post with great details! I'm rushing to meet a deadline and was going to skip trying to find a related problem but I just couldn't pass this up since you made such a clear post and put useful information in which made it easy to track down the problem and propose a solution that hopefully works for you.

Comment: As @scottkosty explains below, it looks like the `svgz` processor was changed, on your machine, possibly due to new software or updates. I use Linux, but not Xubuntu. Have a look in `~/.config` to locate the file that specifies which mimetypes are handled by which software. If necessary, it can be manually edited (although there is probably a GUI for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX uses third-party programs found on your system to perform various conversions. In this case, LyX uses a program to convert the .svgz to a .pdf in the background before it even hands things off to pdfTeX. There have been reports of some problems specifically with converting .svgz. You can see one such recent report [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/search?l=mid&q=Ne96EL6--3-9%40tutanota.com).

To work around the issue on Ubuntu, install the package `librsvg2-bin` and then in Tools > Preferences change the relevant converter to use rsvg-convert. I show a screenshot below. After you make the change, click on the "Modify" button and then "OK".

[image]

> but in previous LyX installations that step was automated and there should be a way to make this work again, I think.

My guess is that it's a 3rd-party application that changed, e.g., Inkscape.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! This somehow solved my problem. However, I had inkscape installed and I switched back and forth between `rsvg-convert -f pdf -o $$o $$i` and the previous entry `inkscape $$i --export-area-drawing --export-filename=$$o` just to test, and now the inkscape command works as well!? That is a bit weird, but at least it solves the issue :)

Comment: Adding to my previous comment. I reproduced this behavior when trying to render a pdf for an own document, which uses svg graphics. Again, I had the pdftex error initially. Then, after modifying the (now uncompressed) "SVG" → "PDF(graphics)" conversion handler to rsvg-convert, it did the job. Changing back to inkscape, it also works now (I cleared the cache by a restart, and the conversion is in the log, now).

Comment: Interesting, that is surprising! Thanks for giving those details. I'm guessing this bug will bite a few users so hopefully they come across this post (well, hopefully the bug will be fixed soon!).